# I can't seem to make the google.cloud.texttospeech to work

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

Im using Python 3.8 and i copy pasted this code as a test.

```
from google.cloud import texttospeech

# Instantiates a client
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

# Set the text input to be synthesized
synthesis_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text="Hello, World!")

# Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml
# voice gender ("neutral")
voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code="en-US", ssml_gender=texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL
)

# Select the type of audio file you want returned
audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.MP3
)

# Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected
# voice parameters and audio file type
response = client.synthesize_speech(
    input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config
)

# The response's audio_content is binary.
with open("output.mp3", "wb") as out:
    # Write the response to the output file.
    out.write(response.audio_content)
    print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

This is the code that is shown by google as can be seen here : [GOOGLE LINK](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries)

Now my problem is that i get this error

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop> & C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe "c:/Users/User/Desktop/from google.cloud import texttospeech.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/from google.cloud import texttospeech.py", line 7, in <module>
    synthesis_input = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text="Hello, World!")
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.texttospeech' has no attribute 'types'
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop>
```

I tried changeing this to add the credentials inside the code but the problem persists.
This is the line i changed:

```
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient(credentials="VoiceAutomated-239f1c05600c.json")
```

Comment: Why did you not change the line that is causing the error instead?

Comment: i tried but then it brings up another error XD, but as i said i took it copy paste from google site so i assume that it shouldnt have any problem whatsoever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error when running that script, i checked the source code and the interface has changed, basically you need to delete all "enums" and "types". It will look similar to this:

```
# Instantiates a client
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

# Set the text input to be synthesized
synthesis_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text="Hello, World!")

# Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml
# voice gender ("neutral")
voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code='en-US',
    ssml_gender=texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)

# Select the type of audio file you want returned
audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.MP3)

# Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected
# voice parameters and audio file type
response = client.synthesize_speech(input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config)

# The response's audio_content is binary.
with open('output.mp3', 'wb') as out:
    # Write the response to the output file.
    out.write(response.audio_content)
    print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

Comment: I get the same error as the OP using your mod which is actually identical to the github version of quickstart.py.

Moreover, in compliance with a prior answer, my version is <2.0:

```google-cloud-texttospeech 1.0.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge```

Comment: I have been using an almost identical script daily since the date of this answer without issues, What if you update your dependencies? I have these:
python = "^3.8"
google-api-python-client = "^1.10.0"
google-cloud-texttospeech = "^2.1.0"
grpcio = "^1.30.0"

Answer (score 5):

I could solve this error by downgrading the library: 
`pip3 install "google-cloud-texttospeech<2.0.0"`

Comment: This is literally the one and only google result for the entire internet that comes up for this exact error if you search for exact matches, and it's saved me twice. Thank you so much.

Comment: I get the same error as the OP and my version is <2.0:

```google-cloud-texttospeech 1.0.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge```

Answer (score 2):

I debug the code and to get it to work i had to write enums and types when needed. Taking the text to speech google documentation example and including some little adjusments:

```
"""Synthesizes speech from the input string of text or ssml.

Note: ssml must be well-formed according to:
    https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/
"""
from google.cloud import texttospeech
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "./config/credentials.json"

# Instantiates a client
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

# Set the text input to be synthesized
synthesis_input = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text="Hello, World!")

# Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml
# voice gender ("neutral")
voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code="en-US", ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL
)

# Select the type of audio file you want returned
audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3
)

# Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected
# voice parameters and audio file type
response = client.synthesize_speech(
    input_=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config
)

# The response's audio_content is binary.
with open("./output_tts/output.mp3", "wb") as out:
    # Write the response to the output file.
    out.write(response.audio_content)
    print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

hope this works for you

Answer (score 1):

It will work Python 3.6 but it won't work with Python 3.7 with latest update of google-cloud-texttospeech. If you want us it with Python 3.7 Try the below code.

```
from google.cloud import texttospeech
def foo():
    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient(credentials=your_google_creds_here)
    translated_text = Text


    synthesis_input = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=translated_text)
    pitch = 1
    speaking_rate = 1
    lang_code = 'en-us' # your_lang_code_hear
    gender = 'male'

    gender_data = {
                    'NEUTRAL': texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL,
                    'FEMALE': texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE,
                    'MALE': texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.MALE
                }

    voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(language_code=lang_code, ssml_gender=gender_data[gender.upper()])
    audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3, speaking_rate=float(speaking_rate), pitch=float(pitch)
    )

    print('Voice config and Audio config : ', voice, audio_config)
    response = client.synthesize_speech(
        synthesis_input, voice, audio_config)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate to version 2.0 visit the site below for details on the changes you need to make since you most likely followed a tutorial using an older version of texttospeech:

```
https://googleapis.dev/python/texttospeech/2.0.0/UPGRADING.html
```

I will also include an example using the beta version of 2.0.0.

```
import google.cloud.texttospeech_v1beta1 as ts
import time

nm = "en-US-Wavenet-I"
hz = 48000
def useTextToSpeech(speaking, lang, speed,stinger):

    client = ts.TextToSpeechClient()
    synthesis_input = ts.SynthesisInput(text=speaking)
    voice = ts.VoiceSelectionParams(

        language_code=lang,
        ssml_gender=ts.SsmlVoiceGender.MALE,
        name=nm,
    )
    audio_config = ts.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=ts.AudioEncoding.OGG_OPUS,
        speaking_rate=speed,
        pitch = 1.2,
        sample_rate_hertz=hz,
         effects_profile_id=['headphone-class-device' ],
    )
    response = client.synthesize_speech(
        request={
            "input": synthesis_input,
            "voice":voice,
            "audio_config":audio_config
                }
                                        )


    with open((stinger+'.opus'), 'wb') as out:
        out.write(response.audio_content)
        print('Audio content written to file  as "'+stinger+'.opus"')
    from playsound import playsound
    import os
    #playsound(os.path.abspath((stinger+'.opus')))
output = str("Make sure when you follow tutorials they are using the most up to date version of the Api!")
useTextToSpeech(output, "en-US-Wavenet-I",1.0,("example"+str(1)))
```